# Can I find the degree of an expression?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, rational-functions

Question: what is the degree of the following expression? $$\frac{x^2+1}{6x-2}$$

If the above question has a degree, please tell me the difference between the degree of a polynomial and the degree of an expression?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By one definition of degree, the degree of a rational function is the difference in the degrees between the numerator and the denominator. Then the degree here is $1$. This means that as $|x|\to\infty$ this behaves like a multiple of $x$, specifically $\frac x6$.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function#Complex_rational_functions the degree of a rational function is sometimes defined as the *maximum* of the degrees of the numerator and denominator, but in some contexts it's taken to be the *difference* of the degrees.

Comment: @BarryCipra Personally, I think taking it to be the maximum of the two degrees is silly. $\frac 1{x^4}$ doesn't behave like a fourth degree polynomial. It has four poles (with multiplicity) rather than roots. $\frac{x^3+1}{x^4-3}$ has three roots and 4 poles. That seems closer to degree $3$ than degree $4$ to me. I don't endorse the definition of the maximum of the two degrees.

Comment: The main advantage I can think of for the "maximum" definition is that it gives an overall sense of how complicated the function is. E.g., a rational function of (maximum) degree $2$ has at most two roots and two poles. The "difference" definition mainly gives information about the function's asymptotic behavior. If anything, it may be a mistake to talk about "the" degree of a rational function; for one thing, unlike polynomials, when you add two rational functions of "degree" $n$, no matter which definition you use, the degree can *increase*.